# How can I Use Unity InputField call a Reference variable

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

My question is : when I typing "@", it will call a dropdown, so I can select a variable from dropdown list, I can typing on the InputFiled like this : my score is @mscore , he score is @hscore . finally I press a button (maybe call "Check out") ,it will show the mscore and hscore the value, just like this:my score is 10 , he score is 8 . how can i do can finish this function？

Comment: Hard to understand what you are asking. Please rephrase your question.

Comment: Are you asking how to make a highschore list to display scores along with a name the player provides?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a complete script which works.

1. Attach the script to the gameobject you want
2. Drag & Drop the inputfield you will type into
3. Specify the parent RectTransform which will have the list of tag suggestions into the `tagsParent` field of the following script. (Mine is anempty I have attached to the InputField with a `VerticalLayoutGroup` attached to it)
4. Create a prefab with a `Text` component and a `Button` component (I've used the standard Button of Unity youcan create in `GameObject` > `UI` menu)
5. Add the prefab to the `tagPrefab` field of the following script
6. Create a button and add a listener to it, select the object with the following script and choose the `ReplaceTags` function

---

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Reflection;

public class AutoFill : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float mscore = 5 ;
    public float hscore = 10 ;

    public InputField inputField;
    public RectTransform tagsParent;
    public RectTransform tagPrefab;

    private List<FieldInfo> fields ;
    private Regex endRegex = new Regex( "@[a-zA-Z0-9]+$" );
    private Regex regex = new Regex( "@[a-zA-Z0-9]+" );

    /// <summary>
    /// Awake is called when the script instance is being loaded
    /// </summary>
    private void Awake()
    {
        fields = GetType().GetFields( BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public )
                        .Where( fieldInfo => fieldInfo.FieldType == typeof( float ) ) // Use this if you want to retrieve only the floating variables
                        .ToList();

        inputField.onValueChanged.AddListener( OnInputValueChanged );
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Called when the value of the input has changed
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="input"></param>
    private void OnInputValueChanged( string input )
    {
        Match match = endRegex.Match( inputField.text );
        if ( match.Success )
        {
            string value = match.Value.Substring(1);
            List<string> tags = GetTagsStartingWith( value );

            FillTagsSuggestions( match.Value, tags );
        }
        else
        {
            FillTagsSuggestions( string.Empty, new List<string>() );
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Fill the tags suggestion
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="tagInput"></param>
    /// <param name="tags"></param>
    private void FillTagsSuggestions( string tagInput, List<string> tags )
    {
        int length = Mathf.Max( tags.Count, tagsParent.childCount );

        for ( int index = 0 ; index < length ; index++ )
        {
            int i = index; // Used to prevent closure problem
            if ( index < tags.Count )
            {
                AddTagSuggestion( tags[index], index, tagInput );
            }
            else if( index < tagsParent.childCount )
            {
                tagsParent.GetChild( index ).gameObject.SetActive( false );
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Adds a tag suggestion
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="tag"></param>
    /// <param name="index"></param>
    /// <param name="tagInput"></param>
    private void AddTagSuggestion( string tag, int index, string tagInput )
    {
        Text text;
        RectTransform suggestionTransform;

        // Get existing button if exists
        if ( index < tagsParent.childCount )
        {
            suggestionTransform = tagsParent.GetChild( index ) as RectTransform;
            suggestionTransform.gameObject.SetActive( true );
            text = suggestionTransform.GetComponentInChildren<Text>();
        }
        // Create new button if does not exist yet
        else
        {
            suggestionTransform = Instantiate( tagPrefab );
            text = suggestionTransform.GetComponentInChildren<Text>();
            suggestionTransform.SetParent( tagsParent, true );
        }

        text.text = tag;

        // Add listener to replace the input by the value of the tag
        Button btn = suggestionTransform.GetComponentInChildren<Button>();
        btn.onClick.RemoveAllListeners();
        btn.onClick.AddListener( () =>
        {
            inputField.text = ReplaceTag( inputField.text, tagInput, tag );
            StartCoroutine( MoveTextEndDelayed() );
        } );
    }

    private System.Collections.IEnumerator MoveTextEndDelayed()
    {
        inputField.Select();
        yield return null;
        inputField.MoveTextEnd( false );
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the tag starting with the given input
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="input"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private FieldInfo GetTagStartingWith( string input )
    {
        return fields.Find( field => field.Name.StartsWith( input ) );
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets all the tags starting with the given input
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="input"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public List<string> GetTagsStartingWith( string input )
    {
        return fields.FindAll( field => field.Name.StartsWith( input ) && field.Name.CompareTo( input ) != 0 ).Select( field => field.Name ).ToList();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Replaces the value in the input by the tagName
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="input"></param>
    /// <param name="value"></param>
    /// <param name="tagName"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public string ReplaceTag( string input, string value, string tagName )
    {
        var fieldInfo = fields.Find( field => field.Name.CompareTo( tagName ) == 0 );
        if ( fieldInfo != null )
            return input.Replace( value, "@" + fieldInfo.Name );

        return input;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Replace all the tags
    /// </summary>
    public void ReplaceTags()
    {
        string input = inputField.text;
        string output = input;

        MatchCollection matches = regex.Matches( input );
        for ( int i = 0 ; i < matches.Count ; i++ )
        {
            Match match = matches[i];
            string tagName = match.Value.Substring(1);
            var fieldInfo = fields.Find( field => field.Name.CompareTo( tagName ) == 0 );
            if ( fieldInfo != null )
                output = output.Replace( matches[i].Value, fieldInfo.GetValue( this ).ToString() );
        }

        inputField.text = output;
        StartCoroutine( MoveTextEndDelayed() );
    }
}
```

---

### OLD ANSWER

It's the very first time I use Reflection on my own, but the following solution seems to work.

```
// Don't forget to add `using System.Linq;` at the beginning of your file

public float mscore = 5 ;
public float hscore = 10 ;

private System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Reflection.FieldInfo> fields ;
private System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex regex = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex( "@[a-zA-Z0-9]+" );


private void Awake()
{
    var bindingFlags = System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance |
        System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic |
        System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public;

    fields = GetType().GetFields( bindingFlags )
                    .Where( fieldInfo => fieldInfo.FieldType == typeof( float ) ) // Use this if you want to retrieve only the floating variables
                    .ToList();

    Debug.Log( ReplaceInput( "my score is @mscore , his score is @hscore" ) );
    // Output "my score is 5 , his score is 10" 
}

public string ReplaceInput( string input )
{
    string output = input;
    System.Text.RegularExpressions.MatchCollection matches = regex.Matches( input );

    for ( int i = 0 ; i < matches.Count ; i++ )
    {
        string fieldName = matches[i].Value.Substring(1);
        var fieldInfo = fields.Find( field => field.Name.CompareTo( fieldName ) == 0 );
        if ( fieldInfo != null )
            output = output.Replace( matches[i].Value, fieldInfo.GetValue( this ).ToString() );
    }

    return output;
}

// Use this function to retrieve the list of variables you can use when you start typing
public System.Collections.Generic.List<string> GetVariables( string input )
{
    return fields.FindAll( field => field.Name.StartsWith( input ) ).Select( field => field.Name ).ToList();
}
```

Comment: Since I didn't understand your question completely, I can't give you additionnal help. You will have to create an additionnal script to populate your dropdown using the `GetVariables` function, and you will be able to replace the input of the user using `ReplaceInput` function (maybe something like `myInputField.onEndEdit.AddListener(delegate {myInputField.text = ReplaceInput(myInputField.text); });`)

Comment: @Mark2 : I'm working on a more complete script. I will update my answer once I'm finished.

Comment: thanks for your reply, it almost what I want.but some little.. when I select from buton(tagprefab), I wish it to be a variable, no show the value , when I press an other button (may call "show"),it will show the value (execute the replace function)

Comment: @Mark2 : I've adapted the script to fill your needs. Please, don't forget to upvote and accept the answer if it has helped you. I've spent couple of hours making you this script ;)